# Создание удаленного рабочего стола на mac os и win

Tags: windows, http, macos, desktop

*Доброго времени суток,*

**Задача:**
Есть два компа: один работает на MacOS, второй win10. Необходимо создать удаленный рабочий стол, таким образом, чтобы иметь возможность удаленно подключаться с компа с win10 на пк с macOS.
Есть ли такая возможность? Если есть, то какие средства(протоколы, программы и тд) необходимо использовать?

*Заранее спасибо*

Comment: Ммм... `teamviewer`?

Comment: TeamViewer не подойдет? Или даже лучше AnyDesk. Или же https://support.microsoft.com/az-latn-az/help/4028379/windows-10-how-to-use-remote-desktop

Comment: https://windowsprofi.ru/win10/kak-nastroit-udalyonnyj-rabochij-stol-windows-10.html